# Why does 'koa-static' middleware keeps returning 404?

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, koa2, koa-router

I'm trying Koa by using koa-static. But it keeps returning `404 (Body: Not Found)` when using multilevel inclusion relationship. I don't know the reason.

**To reproduce**,

- Windows 10 x64, Node v9.11.1
- Koa v2.5.1, koa-compose v4.1.0, koa-static v4.0.3, koa-send v4.1.3

**Directory:**

index.html   index.js   sites/sites.js   sites/onesite/index.js

**index.html**

```
Hello, koa
```

**index.js**

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const router = require('./sites/sites.js')
const app = new Koa()
app.use(router())
app.listen(80)
```

**sites/sites.js**

```
const compose = require('koa-compose')

module.exports = ()=>{
    return (ctx, next)=>{
        compose(require('./onesite').middleware)(ctx, next)
    }
}
```

**sites/onesite/index.js**

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const serve = require('koa-static')

const app = new Koa()
app.use(serve('.'))
module.exports = app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the router you return from `sites.js`:

```
module.exports = ()=>{
  return (ctx, next)=>{
    compose(require('./onesite').middleware)(ctx, next)
  }
}
```

`compose`  is an async function, but you do not wait for its promise to finish. One way to solve this is to return the promise that is returned by `compose` so that `koa` *knows* that it has to wait for that promise to be resolved:

```
module.exports = ()=>{
  return (ctx, next)=>{
    return compose(require('./onesite').middleware)(ctx, next)
  }
}
```

Another way would be to use `await`:

```
module.exports = ()=>{
  return async (ctx, next)=>{
    await compose(require('./onesite').middleware)(ctx, next)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been debugging for a long time.